# How to hide Hangout-chat-bot not responding message from user window?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, google-hangouts, google-chat

I have used rest API to send google chat message "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/xyz/messages/" with valid access_token and also getting proper response from my bot. But every time in sender message I get the message that "bot not responding, Only visible to you" after getting my bot response.

[Click here to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuflU.png)

Comment: I have the same issue... :(
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPaxs.png